# Program to compare directory structures and file and file content between two different locations

Tags: filesystems

Before I give the client the website I save the directories and files.

If there is an error after some time I want to compare the client website structure and files and I want to know:

1. what files and directories are missing on the client side
2. what files and directories are extra (were added) on the client side
3. if some file was changed, show what file was changed and when
4. ability to save the results of the comparison in some log

I know that Total Commander can do some comparison, but it's not enough.

Does some program that can do the things mentioned exist or are my expectations not possible to satisfy with currently available software?

Comment: Without some form of version control it will be difficult to compare files.

Comment: Check the manuals of `rsync` and `diff`.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин I have used Netbeans for comparing files and applying patches in Drupal, but it was jsut for one file. Does it work for the whole directory?

Comment: WinMerge is another software that was made for this task: http://alternativeto.net/software/winmerge/

Answer (score 1):

BeyondCompare does this very nicely, and easily visualized due to colors to indicate added or missing files and folders.
From Scootersoftware:

[image: beyondcompare image]